# Navigation controller is always nil

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I am presenting `UIViewController` like:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

PhotoViewController *resultVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([PhotoViewController class])];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:resultVC animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

I have logged console and result is:

```
po self.navigationController
<UINavigationController: 0x9c3e920>
```

But when i am in `PhotoViewController` class i have logged console and result is :

```
po self.navigationController
nil
```

its nil here. i don't know why this happens. Also i have present with this one but its nil always :

```
[self presentViewController:resultVC animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is nil.
`UIViewController.navigationController` property will only be set if the `ViewController` is pushed, not presented.
A not-so-elegant solution is that you make a global reference(like put the reference in a singleton) to the `NavigationController` before you present it, then you can read it from inside your `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Just learn how work with navigationController.

Replace next code: `[self.navigationController presentViewController:resultVC animated:YES completion:^{}];`
on `[self.navigationController pushViewController:resultVC animated:YES];`

Comment: i don't want to push controller. i want to present controller.

Comment: why? NavigationController can only pushed and Poped. If you need another animation with complietetion, you can use CATransition:

`CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.2f;
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [[[[self.navigationController.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];`

Comment: second, you can create property in PhotoViewController class like UINavigationController. And write to it self.navigationController. But it bad practics. We all need know what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I produce private `navigationController`(here is nav), then assign to the main window, following is the code:

self.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController = self.nav;

you can push the `view controller` with the private `navigationController`

[self.nav pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

It works for me!

But you must export the property `nav` for next or child View Controller to use